# Citation using biblatex-gost

Tags: biblatex, citing

I’m using `biblatex-gost` package, `gost-footnote` style. I have two problems that I can’t resolve:

1. According to GOST, if some bibliography item is cited two or more times in a row, the second, third and so on references should be substituted to “Ibid”. However, if one of those citations is happened to be first on the page, one should specify the entire bibliography item data. As you can see in the MWE it is not the case.
2. If I cite some item, let’s say an article, more than two times (not in a row) the reference in a footnote becomes shortened. `opcittracker=false` setting helped to extend it till the title of the article, but the journal title, year and so on are still not specified.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extreport}

\usepackage{cmap}                           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,bibstyle=gost-numeric,opcittracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

some text some text some text some text some text some\footcite{cummings2004argument} text some text some text some\footcite[P.~335]{cummings2004argument} text some text some text some text

\lipsum

some text some text some text some text some text\footcite{cummings2004argument} some text some text some text some text some text some text some text\footcite{hample1982modeling}

\lipsum

some text some text some text some text some text\footcite{cummings2004argument} some text

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The .bib file:

```
@article{hample1982modeling,
    langid = {english},
    title={Modeling argument},
    author={Hample, Dale},
    journal={Advances in argumentation theory and research},
    pages={259--284},
    year={1982},
    publisher={Southern Illinois University Press Carbondale}
}


@article{cummings2004argument,
    langid = {english},
    title={Argument as Cognition: A Putnamian Criticism of Dale Hample’s Cognitive Conception of Argument},
    author={Cummings, Louise},
    journal={Argumentation},
    volume={18},
    number={3},
    pages={331--348},
    year={2004},
    publisher={Springer}
}
```

**Edit.** There is one more issue and quite surprising one (that's the reason I didn't notice it earlier). If I'm citing some bibliography item for which the `pages` field is filled (usually an article, book chapter, materials in conference proceedings...) and at the same time specifying a particular page as a postnote argument, the reference in the footnote includes both the page range of the article (or another type of item) in a journal and the page I specified. According to GOST, in cases like this the page range should be suppressed. In other words, I want to get

`Author Name. Article Title // Journal name. Year. Vol. 1, no 2. P. 10`

instead of

`Author Name. Article Title // Journal name. Year. Vol. 1, no 2. Pp. 5-15.  P. 10.`

MWE (includes the previous solution):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{extreport}

\usepackage{cmap}                           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-footnote,language=auto,autolang=other,bibstyle=gost-numeric,opcittracker=false,pagetracker]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:seen}{%  the same for cite and footcite
    \iffirstonpage
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\ifopcit
            {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
            {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:seen}{%  the same for cite and footcite
    \iffirstonpage
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
        {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
        {\ifopcit
            {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
            {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
                {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

some text some text some\footcite[P.~335]{cummings2004argument} text some text some text some text


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you have a new question, it is a good idea to ask a new question for that. It is sufficiently unrelated to the other questions here to warrant a new question anyway. (We prefer to ask only one question per question, anyway.)

Comment: @moewe Sorry, you are right. I'll do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first problem you will want to change instances of `\ifciteibid` to `\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}` (you will also have to enable the `pagetracker` option)

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,sorting=nyt,style=gost-footnote,bibstyle=gost-numeric,opcittracker=false,pagetracker]{biblatex}
```

AFAIK you will only have to change

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:seen}{%  the same for cite and footcite
  \iffirstonpage
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
      {\ifopcit
        {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
        {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:short}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}}
```

---

If with your second point you mean to say that you want to see a full citation for subsequent citations, you will want to change all `cite:short`s in the above code to `cite:full`

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:seen}{%  the same for cite and footcite
  \iffirstonpage
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
    {\ifthenelse{\ifciteibid\AND\NOT\iffirstonpage}
      {\usebibmacro{cite:ibid}}
      {\ifopcit
        {\usebibmacro{cite:opcit}}
        {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:full}}
          {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}}}}
```